# Angularjs factory/service management

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

We are working on a large scale application based on angularjs, now based on some best practices we develop a model using factory services, such that it can be shared across controllers. Since, we have many models across modules the no of factory services increased exponentially, hence memory consumption of the browser.

My question was how these singleton services can be managed if we have many in the project? How can we destroy effectively, before application can destroyed as a whole?